# Formula to create representative-sized rectangular map cell grids from degrees

Tags: r, grids-graticules

I'm a novice user in R.

I have a dataset consisted of coordinates of some "kind of centroids" of grid cells and my question is if any formula exists to create representative sized grid cells using the size parameter of `geom_point`, knowing the size of my cell in degrees.

Here is an example of my code:

```
x <- ggmap(map) +
      geom_point(data = df, 
                aes(colour= zscore), shape=15,alpha=0.8,

                size = varsize)
```

For example, in case I know the cell grids are 0.05 in degrees, which size would be preferred to use in my code ?

Here is an example of my grid using `size=2`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to control size of points as you expect... would probably use geom_rect:

```
geom_rect(data = df, 
          aes(xmin = x-.025, xmax = x+.025, ymin = y-.025, ymax = y+.025), 
              alpha=0, colour="red", fill= "red"))
```